# list element with odd index skipping iteration, why?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to remove all elements of a list that do not match a given regular expression. I am using the following code:

```
import json
import re

skus = [u'12', u'344', u'56', u'PSJAI12345', u'57']
pattern = re.compile('([A-Z]{5})(\d{5})')
for sku in skus:
        if pattern.match(sku):
                print("skip")
        else:
                skus.remove(sku)

print json.dumps(skus)
```

The output is:

```
["344", "PSJAI12345"]
```

the expected output was:

```
["PSJAI12345"]
```

It seems like items with odd index are somehow skipping iteration (`skip` not getting printed when `PSJAI12345` matched the regular expression). I can't understand why. Please can someone explain what's going on here.

Comment: You're modifying your list within the loop. Doing this is not recommended, if necessary requires careful debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the sequence/mapping while you're iterating it.

Here's an alternative using list comprehension (instead of modifying the list, returning new one):

```
import re
import json

skus = [u'12', u'344', u'56', u'PSJAI12345', u'57']
pattern = re.compile('([A-Z]{5})(\d{5})')
skus = [sku for sku in skus if pattern.match(sku)]  # OR skus[:] = ...
print json.dumps(skus)
```

output:

```
["PSJAI12345"]
```

---

Alternatively, iterate the copy of the original list (this is not recommended though, it is slow because `remove` search the element from the beginning).

```
for sku in skus[:]:
    if pattern.match(sku):
        print("skip")
    else:
        skus.remove(sku)
```